# How to change Primary Output Source Path in Visual Studio 2010 Setup Deployment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I change Primary Output Source Path in Visual Studio 2010 Setup Deployment?

Currently the source path is:
C:\VisualC#\Projects\MyApp\Obj\x86\Release\myapp.exe

I want to change the source path to bin\release\

so when I build my setup, it packages bin\release assembly.

Comment: Fawad Naseer, did you manage to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify post build events in your project file.
Follow the steps below:

1. In Solution Explorer, select the project for which you want to
   specify the build event.
2. On the Project menu, click Properties.
3. Select the Build Events tab.
4. In the Post-build event command line box, specify the syntax of the
   build event.
5. In the Run the post-build event box, specify under what conditions
   to run the post-build event.

You can use the guide provided by MSDN here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

And if you'd like to use any common Macros, here is a list provided by MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

I hope it supports your question, please don't hesitate to ask if not.